# How can you make a predictive model trained in R available for scoring via an HTTP endpoint?

Tags: r, production, plumber, pmml

I have a predictive model trained in R on a large dataset. Now I need to export that trained model so that I can use it for future prediction/scoring of new cases. I am unsure what are the best ways to do so. I have seen that there is something called [PMML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) which could be used for exporting some models, but it requires both that the exact model is supported by the PMML package + I need a parser to apply the PMML in whatever language my web service is written in. Are the better/more modern ways of doing this?

I have read about approaches where the trained model is saved as and `.rds` file which can then be loaded into an R-deamon process and poked at using HTTP via e.g. [plumber](https://www.rplumber.io) - but I wonder if that is really a production scale solution?

Comment: This isn't really specific enough to be answerable. It depends on a lot of factors. Exactly what type of model are you fitting? Have you done any benchmarking on memory/time require to make predictions? How often will the endpoint be hit? What are the max response times you allow. What exactly is your "production scale"? I'm not sure there's really anything specific about R or model prediction in this question that make it different than standing up any web application for "production". Software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Hi again, my model is a GX boost model

Answer (score 1):

Convert your R model to PMML document using the [`r2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package, and then deploy this PMML document as an HTTP endpoint using the [Openscoring](https://github.com/openscoring/openscoring) REST web service.

If your R model type is supported, then the whole process takes <1 min from the get-go, and is technically very solid/modern/competitive. If your R model type is not yet supported, then please open a feature request with the `r2pmml` project's issue tracker to make it happen.